# How to use Lucene's DistinctValuesCollector?

Tags: kotlin, lucene

My objective is to collect distinct values of select fields to provided them as filter options for the frontend. `DistinctValuesCollector` seems to be the tool for this, however  since I haven't found code sample and documentation except for the Javadocs I can't currently correctly construct this collector. Can anyone provide an example?

This is my attempt which doesn't deliver the desired distinct values of the field `PROJEKTSTATUS.name`.

```kotlin
val groupSelector = TermGroupSelector(PROJEKTSTATUS.name)
val searchGroup = SearchGroup<BytesRef>()
val valueSelector = TermGroupSelector(PROJEKTSTATUS.name)
val groups = mutableListOf(searchGroup)
val distinctValuesCollector = DistinctValuesCollector(groupSelector, groups, valueSelector)
```

That field is indexed as follows:

```kotlin
document.add(TextField(PROJEKTSTATUS.name, aggregat.projektstatus, YES))
document.add(SortedDocValuesField(PROJEKTSTATUS.name, BytesRef(aggregat.projektstatus)))
```

Comment: Latest version of Lucene - and Java not Kotlin... but in case it helps, you can look at the code in the official testing class [here](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/47f8c1baa2e8d25fd60c886ec7ce09a81ee7d668/lucene/grouping/src/test/org/apache/lucene/search/grouping/TestDistinctValuesCollector.java). I have never used `DistinctValuesCollector `, so I can't comment on the testing code.

Comment: @andrewJames That's helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @andrewJames's hint to a test class I could figure it out:

```kotlin
fun IndexSearcher.collectFilterOptions(query: Query, field: String, topNGroups: Int = 128, mapper: Function<String?, String?> = Function { it }): Set<String?> {
    val firstPassGroupingCollector = FirstPassGroupingCollector(TermGroupSelector(field), Sort(), topNGroups)
    search(query, firstPassGroupingCollector)
    val topGroups = firstPassGroupingCollector.getTopGroups(0)
    val groupSelector = firstPassGroupingCollector.groupSelector
    val distinctValuesCollector = DistinctValuesCollector(groupSelector, topGroups, groupSelector)
    search(query, distinctValuesCollector)
    return distinctValuesCollector.groups.map { mapper.apply(it.groupValue.utf8ToString()) }.toSet()
}
```